# Is this a good reason to use a service bus, alternatives please

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture, esb

I'm in the planning phase of our new site - it's an extension of some mobile apps we've built. We want to provide our users with a central point for communication and also provide features for users who don't want to/can't use the mobile apps. One of the features we're looking at adding is a reputation system similar in nature to the SO badge system. We're designing the system to use SOA.

I don't want to have to code all of this logic into the main app as discreet chunks. I'm thinking of creating a means to accomplish this which will allow us to define new thresholds and rules for gaining reputation and have them injected into some service. The two ways I've thought of doing this so far are:

1. To look for certain traits in a users actions and respond, this would mean having a service running that can run through the 'plugged in' award definitions and check for thresholds that have been met and respond appropriately.
2. To fire events when the user performs actions - listen out for those events and respond appropriately. Because the services which will be carrying out these actions are running in separate app domains potentially on separate servers the only way I can see having a central message bus to listen and respond to these events is by using something like MassTransit, nServiceBus or Rhino.Esb.

I know that using a service bus can very easily be inappropriately designed into an application that simply doesn't need it and most times - unless you're integrating disparate, heterogenous systems - you most likely won't need one when designing a new system  but I'm a bit lost for options as to the best way to do this. I don't like the idea of having a service hammer the Db all the time in the background. But it does sound like it might be a lot simpler early on - later on - I dread to think!

Has anyone here designed a system like this? How did you accomplish this? We're designing for high throughput as we expect there will be times when the system will need to be able to cope with bursts of users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've designed a system that had similar requirements. To achieve this the key elements were:

- Plugins
- Event messaging - using [Emesary](http://emesary.codeplex.com/)

The basic concept is that the *core* is not aware of exactly which module will perform any given task.

The messages are defined and at points within the system they are dispatched. The sender is not aware if the message is required. This effectively decouples vast chunks of the system.

So to perform a job some code is plugged in, that registers with the event messaging bus and will receive messages. When it receives a message that it needs to process it will process it.

The Emesary code is extremely small and efficient in the first instance I've called it ([Emesary](http://chateau-logic.com/content/c-wpf-application-plumbing-using-emesary) and you're free to use it; or from [Emesary CodePlex](http://emesary.codeplex.com/)

As the system becomes more complex it is possible that there are lots of events flying about, if you get more than 20k a second it was always in my design to add filtering and routing (implemented by the recipient interface being extended to allow a recipient to specify messages it wants to receive during registration). I've never needed to add this filtering because Emesary is sufficiently efficient that it is the processing of the messages that takes the time.

I've build a version of Emesary which bridges two Notifiers across disparate systems using WCF, Corba and TCP/IP. I investigated using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and decided it was possible to use this underneath Emesary if needed.

### Base Class Diagram

[image: Emesary Class Diagram]

### Scalable server.

This is a fairly complex example however it shows where Emesary fits in. In this diagram anything with a drop shadow can have multiple instances and this is managed outside of what I'm trying to explain here.

[image: scalable application server]

Comment: Hi cheers for that - i'll take a look at the project - I guess now all that's left is to figure out which service bus implementation would be best to handle the pubsub design?

Comment: I haven't tried this out yet, had a look at the code though. Do you have any example code using this in combination with an ESB?

Comment: I've got a Emesary -> RabbitMQ (somewhere). I'll try to dig it out and post it.